# Merging two SQL Server tables conditionally into a third table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Clearly, I am not a SQL guy, so I have to ask for help on the following rather simple task.

I have two SQL Server 2008 tables: `t1` and `t2` with many identical columns and a key column (`entry_ID`). `T2` has rows that do not exist in `t1` but should.

I want to merge those rows from `t2` that do not exist in `t1` but I also do not want any rows from `t2` that already exist in `t1`. I would like the result set to fill a new `t3`.

I have looked at many solutions online but can't find the solution to the above scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) should help you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it you could use `UNION ALL` or `OUTER JOIN`.

Assuming you are using Entry_ID to find identical records, and Entry_ID is unique within each table, here is a `OUTER JOIN` method:

This gets you your recordset: T1 and T2 merged:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN T1.Entry_ID IS NULL THEN 'T2'
WHEN T2.Entry_ID IS NULL THEN 'T1'
ELSE 'Both'
END SourceTable,
COALESCE(T1.Entry_ID,T2.Entry_ID) As Entry_ID,
COALESCE(T1.Col1, T2.Col1) As Col1,
COALESCE(T1.Col2, T2.Col2) As Col2,
COALESCE(T1.Col3, T2.Col3) As Col3,
COALESCE(T1.Col4, T2.Col4) As Col4
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2
ON T1.Entry_DI = T2.Entry_ID
ORDER BY COALESCE(T1.Entry_DI,T2.Entry_ID)
```

This inserts it into T3:

```
INSERT INTO T3 (Entry_ID,Col1, COl2,Col3,Col4)
SELECT 
COALESCE(T1.Entry_DI,T2.Entry_ID) As Entry_ID,
COALESCE(T1.Col1, T2.Col1) As Col1,
COALESCE(T1.Col2, T2.Col2) As Col2,
COALESCE(T1.Col3, T2.Col3) As Col3,
COALESCE(T1.Col4, T2.Col4) As Col4
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2
ON T1.Entry_DI = T2.Entry_ID
```

Again you must note that Entry_ID needs to be unique within their tables, and it uses this to match between the tables.

Also note the columns from the select line up with the column list in the insert statement - the order of the columns in the physical table doesn't matter, the INSERT and SELECT just have to line up.

Comment: Yes, Entry_ID is the Primary Key in both tables.  I will use your solution Tuesday.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: But does Entry_ID = 4 in T1 and Entry_ID = 4 in T2 indicate that these are the same records? Often this is not the case. Often you need to use a bunch of other fields to work out whether the record is the same.

Comment: Good point.  Turns out that one field in t2 is different but that difference is valid., but when Entry_ID's are the same in both tables, it means

Comment: Okay, here's the results from the SELECT and INSERT.  I have changed the Col1, Col2... to the actual table column names.  Also, note the entry_ID column is not the first column in the table, so I adjusted your first line accordingly in both the SELECT and INSERT.  When I execute the first SELECT I get 142 rows.  I should be getting t1 count of 292 PLUS some portion of t2 count of 578.  I will paste my SQL lines in a folliwing Comment...

Comment: "SQL code is too many characters in this Comment field."  How can I send the SQL command lines to you?

Comment: I may not have explained my scenario well enough.  Here is an example of what I'm needing to do...

t1
col1 col2 entry_ID col4
AA BB 1  CC
DD EE 3  FF
GG HH 4  II

t2
col1 col2 entry_ID col4
AA BB 1  CC
QQ WW 2  YY
GG HH 4  II

Result needed in t3
col1 col2 entry_ID col4
AA BB 1  CC (t1 row)
QQ WW 2  YY (t2 row)
DD EE 3  FF (t1 row)
GG HH 4  II (t1 row)

Comment: Somehow I put an incorrect WHERE in the SELECT caluse. I've fixed the original post. The order of columns in your table is irrelevant. It inserts the selected columns in order with the INSERT statement.

Comment: I pulled the WHERE clauses in both the first section and the second section of clauses.  Ran the first and get what I expect: 832 merged rows from t1 and t2.  When I then run the second INSERT clauses it does not populate t3 at all.  BTW, I use the real column and table names, not the Col1, Col2...

Comment: When you run the INSERT does it say 0 rows affected? Because that dataset you are getting from the select should be inserted straight into T3.

Comment: I just ran the first set of clauses and then ran the second set and got the error: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table CareMinistry_BK_08112013_new"  I used SET IDENTITY_INSERT t3 ON with the second set of clauses and it produced 832 rows!  I then did a Select * from t3 and it returned 832 rows.  Seems to me your select and Insert clauses worked!!  I will do more testing to verify this result.

Comment: Good stuff. Well done for solving your own IDENTITY_INSERT problem. Don't forget to turn it off again if you are going to use this table

Comment: Well done on the expert level.  Thanks for your patience and knowledge.

Comment: On further inspection of table t3, I see the insert into/select did not work as I expected as it contains exactly the same rows as t1 even though the 1st select clauses did the merge t1-t2 correctly--which produced 837 rows.  Doing a select * from t3, the t1 rows show up 401 rows--the same rows and entry_IDs as t1.

Comment: follow-up:  t1 contains entry_IDs from 8-964, with gaps in entry_IDs (404 rows).  t2 contains entry_IDs from 8-709 with gaps (578 rows).  t3 should contain the sequential entry_IDs of 8-964 from t1 and t2 merge, but shows the same entry_IDs as in t1 (404 rows).

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. Perhaps you should empty the table `TRUNCATE T3`, run the select and verify it (I've added an order by). If the select doesn't return what you expect, pick some sample rows and try and work out why.

Comment: Clearly your tables are not called t1,t2,t3 etc., perhaps a mistake has been made when transcribing from my sample code to the real tables. I've added another column, 'sourcetable' to the original select to try and troubleshoot.

Comment: Correct, I just use t1, t2, t3 to shorten the # of chars. in my Comment box.  Also, you have "ON T1.Entry_DI = T2.Entry_ID
ORDER BY COALESCE(T1.Entry_DI,T2.Entry_ID)"  I have assumed that "Entry_DI" in your clauses are a typo and should be "Entry_ID"  Correct?

Comment: Success!  In retrospect, my mistake was in working with too way many chars. modifying your clauses to my scenario while testing with the result of making many mistakes. The "t3" result now shows 840 rows with the appropriate Entry_IDs in sequence.  Thank you so very much for staying with me on this.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)